# Upgrade Windows 8 standard edition to professional edition

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-8-upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade Windows 8 standard edition to professional edition? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you simply buy an upgrade kit.

[See here](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msuk/en_GB/pdp/productID.257642500) for details

Answer (score 2):

Open up search on the charms bar and look up "Upgrade" in settings. For the next step it will ask you for a Windows 8 serial. Now this part I'm not sure if its the Standard or the Pro serial but preferably the Pro serial will do. Once that's done you just follow the installer instructions and it will install Windows 8 pro and its features along with it.