# Is it possible to upgrade from Windows 8 OEM to Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, oem, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing a different edition of Windows 8 on an OEM system](https://superuser.com/questions/512123/installing-a-different-edition-of-windows-8-on-an-oem-system)

I've just built a new computer and purchased the OEM (System Builder) version of Windows 8 (64-bit). I bought the non-Pro version, figuring I could upgrade later if & when I need to. However, I've heard rumours that it's not possible to upgrade the OEM edition. Is this true? Has anyone out there successfully upgraded from Windows 8 OEM to Windows Pro? Or can anyone running Windows 8 OEM confirm that an upgrade is available, even if they haven't used it?

(nb. I realise this is very similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498244/upgrade-windows-8-standard-edition-to-professional-edition), but I'm asking separately because my concern is specifically with the OEM / System Builder version of Windows 8)

Comment: Cannot confirm, but I see no reason whatsoever that the same Pro Pack upgrade won't work with the System Builder version of Windows 8 Core/Standard as well. After all, it works fine with Windows 8 Core/Standard that comes pre-installed on new PCs.

Comment: I think you're probably right. My only reason for worrying is [this article](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/138983-the-cheapest-windows-8-upgrade-and-oem-deals) which says "Microsoft won’t even sell you an upgrade to this version". Re-reading it I suspect they actually just mean that the upgrades from other versions of Windows that MS are selling all go straight to Pro, but it's not totally clear. I'd rather just go out and buy Pro than find out afterwards I can't upgrade.

Comment: "I'd rather just go out and buy Pro than find out afterwards I can't upgrade." - Sure, if you can, why not do so?

Comment: Well, because it's more expensive and I don't know that I need the extra features. If I can upgrade later it makes sense to get the cheaper version to start with.